# Does Google Cloud ML only support distributed Tensorflow for Multiple GPU training jobs?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'd like to run a Tensorflow application using multiple GPU's on Cloud ML.

My Tensorflow application is written in the non-distributed paradigm, that is outlined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus)

From what I understand if I want to use Cloud ML to run this same application, with multiple GPU's then the application must use scale tier CUSTOM and I need to set up parameter servers, worker servers which seem to be a distributed-tensorflow paradigm. [Link here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus)

Is this the only way to run multiple GPU training jobs on Cloud ML?

Is there a guide that helps me scope the changes required for my multiGPU (tower based) training application to a distributed tensorflow application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CUSTOM tier with only a single master node, and no workers/parameter servers. Those are optional parameters.

Then `complex_model_m_gpu` has 4 GPUs, and `complex_model_l_gpu` has 8.